# ¿Cómo leer correctamente valores con serialport en node js?

Tags: nodejs, arduino, serialport

Tengo el siguiente código el cual lee del puerto serial valores que se envían por medio de Arduino.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline("\n")
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnected', function(){
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

var clearData = "";
var readData = "";

serialPort.on('open',function(){
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        readData += data.toString();
        io.sockets.emit('message',data);
    });
});
```

Este es el código que tengo en Arduino, en este caso sólo imprimo **hola** ya que es un ejemplo:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("Hello");
delay(2000);
}
```

Pero lo que obtengo en la consola al leer los valores con serialport en node js se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer para recibir los datos correctamente?, es decir todo en una sola línea.

Hello

Hello

Hello

Answer (score 2):

Si no tienes un protocolo, o el unico protocolo es basado en tiempo (delay(2000)) entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    serialPort.on('open',function(){
        let _timer
        let buf = ''

        console.log('open');

        serialPort.on('data', function (data){
            console.log(data);

            clearTimeout (_timer)
            _timer = setTimeout (function () {

                io.sockets.emit('message',buf);
                buf = ''

            }, 500) // nothing received in 500ms, then packet has finished

            buf = buf + data    
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

yo me comunico con Arduino desde un linux, puede que tenga algo que ver, pero por si acaso, utilizo la siguiente forma de definir el puerto

```
const portArduino = new serialport('/dev/ttyACM0', {
    baudRate: 9600
});
const parsers = serialport.parsers;
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
    delimiter: '\r\n'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo estoy usando la ultima versión de Serialport hasta el momento (7.0.2) y esto me funciono a mi:

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Delimiter = require('@serialport/parser-delimiter');

var port = new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbmodem141101');

var parser = port.pipe(new Delimiter({ delimiter: '\n' }));

parser.on('data', function(data){
  data = data.toString();
  console.log(data);
})
```

lo leí en https://serialport.io/docs/en/api-parser-delimiter